# Math.sqrt() abbreviation javascript

Tags: javascript

my question is, in **javascript** exist any way to **abbreviate** **Math.sqrt()** to only **sqrt()**?

To be like this:

```
var value = Math.sqrt(10)
```

to

```
var value = sqrt(10)
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: You can make a function called `sqrt` that uses `Math.sqrt`.

Comment: `var sqrt = Math.sqrt; sqrt(10);` seems to work in Chrome. If there's any doubt about it, you can do `var sqrt = Math.sqrt.bind(Math)`

Comment: You could [destructure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) it: `const { sqrt } = Math`

Answer (score 2):

Yes, because variables (or constants) can reference funtion expressions.

```js
const sqrt = Math.sqrt

var value = sqrt(10)
console.log(value);
```

You can also bring multiple functions for `Math` into scope using your own alias

```js
const { sqrt, floor } = Math;

const value = floor(sqrt(10));
console.log(value);
```